# Limiting the size of the managed heap in a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Can I configure my C# application to limit its memory consumption to, say, 200MB?
IOW, I don't want to wait for the automatic GC (which seems to allow the heap to grow much more than actually needed by this application).

I know that in Java there's a command line switch you can pass to the JVM that achieves this.. is there an equivalent in C#?

p.s.

I know that I can invoke the GC from code, but that's something I would rather not have to do periodically. I'd rather set it once upon startup somehow and forget it.

Comment: Something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834042/net-generation-0-heap-size

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this? Garbage collectors operating in an artificially constrained memory environment tend to perform worse that those allowed to use more memory.

Comment: In this particular case there are other (native) applications living on the machine that cannot afford the GCed app taking so much memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any such options for the regular CLR. I would imagine that you can control this if you implement your own CLR host.

However, I disagree in your assessment of how the heap grows. The heap grows because your application is allocating and holding on to objects.

There are a couple of things you can do to limit the memory usage. Please see this question for some input: [Reducing memory usage of .NET applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343374/reducing-memory-usage-of-net-applications/1343394#1343394)

Comment: This is the observed behavior: the system runs in a loop and the working set size grows indefinitely. When GC is run explicitly, in code, every once in a while, the working set size remains constant. I realize that there's something fishy going on here, but the fact that running GC keeps the WS constant tells me that the application is _not_ holding on to objects.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CLR manages OS allocated memory on behalf of your application. Thus you cannot necessarily expect to see an immediate drop in working set size after cleanup. The GC tunes itself for better performance, and if segments of memory are not needed, they will eventually be released to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

> The memory manager lets the host
>   provide an interface through which the
>   CLR will request all memory
>   allocations. It replaces both the
>   Windows® memory APIs and the standard
>   C CLR allocation routines. Moreover,
>   the interface allows the CLR to inform
>   the host of the consequences of
>   failing a particular allocation (for
>   example, failing a memory allocation
>   from a thread holding a lock may have
>   certain reliability consequences). It
>   also permits the host to customize the
>   CLR's response to a failed allocation,
>   ranging from an OutOfMemoryException
>   being thrown all the way up through
>   the process being torn down. The host
>   can also use this manager to recapture
>   memory from the CLR by unloading
>   unused app domains and forcing garbage
>   collection. The memory manager
>   interfaces are listed in

Source and More : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx#S2

**Edit :**

I actually wouldn't recommend you to manage memory by yourself, because more you get in, more problems you will probably run into, instead CLR does that mission perfectly.

But if you say it's very important for me to handle things on my own, then I can't anything.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something I'd want to do. I was hoping for a configurable switch, like in Java. In fact, I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why there wouldn't be such a switch. I mean, somewhere, something is deciding when to run GC based on some limit/heuristic, and it seems reasonable to want to be able to configure that limit. Again.. Java allows this..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out, but you could attempt to call [SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686237(VS.85).aspx) passing in the right flags to enforce that your process never gets more than so much memory. I don't know if the GC will take this into account and clean up more often, or if you'll just get OutOfMemoryExceptions.