# How do I increase heap size for running .NET Core 1.x/2.x tests in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

My tests run all the way through on the command line (using `dotnet.exe test`), but when running them within Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2017, some of the tests are crashing. Due to notes I have from prior debugging efforts, one particular test crashes with an out of memory exception (I had to reduce the scope of the test in order to prevent it from crashing).

I am testing on .NET Framework 4.5.1, .NET Core 1.0, and .NET Core 2.0 (the current scenario is on .NET Core 1.0).

What I am wondering is if there is an official way to increase the heap size of Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2017?

> NOTE: Ideally, I'd like to put together a command or configuration that is automated so that anyone who clones my repo and runs tests in Visual Studio 2017+ will have the increased heap size.

### What I Tried

I discovered [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2010/09/27/out-of-memory-easy-ways-to-increase-the-memory-available-to-your-program/) that explains how to do increase memory, but it is meant for increasing the size of an EXE that you are developing, not for testing. I followed the instructions to use the `editbin.exe` utility to try to increase `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe`, but this didn't seem to have any effect (the test still crashes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heap size in C# / .Net Framework - Can it grow and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042928/heap-size-in-c-sharp-net-framework-can-it-grow-and-how)

Comment: Is your test running in a 32 or 64 bit environment? test explorer may launch it in 32bit which limits your heap.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - Good point. I have been testing under x86 in Visual Studio.  I will give x64 a try.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - That did the trick. Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it. And probably should note that the setting is under Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture > X64, since it is difficult to find if you don't know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when your tests are run in a 32bit host which limits your available memory.

The VS-integrated test explorer can run both in 32 and 64 bit mode, with 32 usually being the default. This can be easily changed through the menu `Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture` menu:

[image]